# How to use generic parameters that depend on other generic parameters for entities?

Tags: syntax, vhdl

I am trying to convert some Verilog code that produces a slower clock from a faster clock for a UART module.  The original verilog code is based on the module over at fpga4fun.com, and this is my attempt to translate it for my VHDL-based design.

```
entity baud_generator is
generic(
    f_clk : integer := 50000000;  -- default: 50 MHz
    baud  : integer := 115200;    -- default: 115,200 baud
    accum_width : integer := 16;
    accum_inc : integer := (baud sll accum_width) / f_clk
);
port(
    clock : in std_logic;
    reset_n : in std_logic;
    enable : in std_logic;
    baud_clock : out std_logic
);  
end entity baud_generator;
```

However, my compiler, Aldec-HDL, doesn't like the following line:

```
 accum_inc : natural := (baud sll accum_width) / f_clk
```

Here is the exact error message:

```
 # Error: COMP96_0300: baud_generator.vhd : (20, 52): Cannot reference "f_clk" until the interface list is complete.
 # Error: COMP96_0300: baud_generator.vhd : (20, 28): Cannot reference "baud" until the interface list is complete.
 # Error: COMP96_0071: baud_generator.vhd : (20, 28): Operator "sll" is not defined for such operands.
 # Error: COMP96_0104: baud_generator.vhd : (20, 27): Undefined type of expression.
 # Error: COMP96_0077: baud_generator.vhd : (20, 27): Assignment target incompatible with right side. Expected type 'INTEGER'.
```

In verilog, I have something like this:

```
module baud_generator(
  input clock,
  input reset_n,
  input enable,
  output baud_clock
);
parameter f_clock = 50000000;
parameter baud    = 115200;
parameter accum_width = 16;
parameter accum_inc = (baud << accum_width) / f_clock;
//...
endmodule
```

What is it that I need to modify in that line to make the compiler happy?  Is it possible to use generics chained together like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This basically says you cannot do computations with the generic values to caluclate (default values for) other generics.

Just use `accum_inc` as a constant, not as a generic.

Also, the SLL (shift logic left) operator is meant for bit patterns (`unsigned` and `signed` datatypes in the `ieee.numeric_std` and `ieee.numeric_bit` packages), not for integers. You can do the same by multiplying by a power of two.

Comment: Time to get a more comprehensive VHDL book I think!  My combo digital logic + VHDL doesn't go much into these areas.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like `accum_inc` is a constant, not a parameter (as it's calculated from the generics, so there's no reason to override it)

So it doesn't want to be in the generic part - simply move it to the architecture and make it a constant (and as Philippe noted, do your shifting with multiplies):

```
constant accum_inc : integer := (baud * (2**accum_width)) / f_clk;
```

You may find that you overflow what `integer`s can manage, depending on the values of the generics, so you might find you want to use `unsigned` vectors in the generics and/or calculation.

Comment: Yes, it would be a constant at 'compile' so that I don't actually have to implement dividers and what not in my HDL and lose area on the FPGA>  I'm thinking I can make accum_inc a constant variable in my architecture then?

Comment: Yes, that's what you should do. It *must* be constant as it depends on generics, which are constants by the time you elaborate the design.